# Detecting collisions of enemies

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I need to detect the collisions of the same type of enemies in XNA.
If a collision is detected, I wanted the enemies to turn around and walk in the other direction.

If i save all instances to a List how can I detect if different(But same) type of enemies collide?

This is in C# XNA.

EDIT: I have enemies that are in a class called "Enemy", all enemies in my game are created from this class, I need to be able to check if the enemies have collided.

EDIT 2:

Here is a code sample:

```
    // Fields.        
    private List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();

    // Add our enemies when we need to.
    enemies.Add(new Enemy(this, position, spriteSet));

    // Here is it's update method.
    private void UpdateEnemies(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.Update(gameTime);

            // This code works because it's comparing the player.
            if (enemy.BoundingRectangle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
            {
                OnPlayerKilled(enemy);
            }
            // This code is always ture because enemy is enemy I can't figure out how to solve this.
                            if (enemy.BoundingRectangle.Intersects(enemy.BoundingRectangle))
            {
                // Make enemies turn... This if statement is the problem.
            }
        }
```

Comment: By for each two enemies checking if their location is the same and their typs are.

Comment: And I 'ms orry, but we're unable to give ou a more helpful answer unles you give us more details about your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if two enemies have collided, you need to find the Rectangle each of them is occupying. Then you can use [`Rectangle.Intersects(Rectangle)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464123.aspx) to find out if they are overlapping.

Re: Edit:

Every enemy is always checking for collision with itself. Not what you want :(|)

Something like this is what you want:

```
foreach (Enemy enemy1 in enemies)
{
    foreach (Enemy enemy2 in enemies)
    {
        if (enemy1 != enemy2 && enemy1.BoundingRectangle.Intersects(enemy2.BoundingRectangle))
        {
            // enemy1 is colliding!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this all enemies think they are colliding, that's what I tried before asking this question.

Comment: I need to know how to differentiate the enemy objects before testing using the Intersects method.

Comment: Then check if the two enemies are the same type. That's all I can say with the information you gave.

Comment: what would that matter? If each enemy is just an object of the Enemy class, then they are all the same, so if i check for a collision, there is always a collision with themselves. Understand?

Comment: You made it sound like you have several types of enemies that only collide with their type. If you have a problem with an enemy colliding with itself, then in your collision routine you need to check that the two enemies are not the same enemy, of course.

Comment: No you don't understand, there is one type of enemy in the game, and I can't figure out how to differentiate each so that I can see if they intersect.

Comment: What is your specific question? There are many aspects to collision detection. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have edited my post to show a code sample of what im talking about.

Comment: Yes that code is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much!